# Determine an operator on a Hilbert space based on a polynomial equation

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose we have an infinite dimensional, separable Hilbert space and an operator $X$ on that Hilbert space  for which we only know that

$$ X^2 + bX + c = 0 \qquad (1) $$

with $b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

With $p,q\in \mathbb{C}$ and

$$ (X - p)(X - q) = 0 $$
$$ b = -p-q, \quad pq = c $$

we can introduce projection operators $E_{p,q}$ satisfying

$$ E_p + E_q = \text{id} $$
$$ E_p^2 = E_p, \quad E_q^2 = E_q, \quad E_p E_q = E_q E_p = 0 $$

and set

$$ X = p \, E_p + q E_q \qquad (2) $$

which obviously solves $(1)$.

**Question**: Are there other solutions for which X is not simply given by $(2)$ using a pair of projectors $E_{p,q}$?

Comment: For $b=c=0$ the equation $X^2=0$ admits many solutions. For example $Xx=\langle x,v\rangle w,$ where $v\perp w.$

Comment: Thanks. I am interested in the general case.

Comment: I have no knowledge of functional analysis, but perhaps you could check that $\mathbf{C}[X]$ forms a ring which is commutative and doesn’t have any trivial zero divisors. Then it follows that the polynomial has at most two zeros, and you can check then whether the polynomial is separable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $p=q.$ Let $Y$ be an operator such that ${\rm Im}\,Y\subset \ker Y,$ i.e. $Y^2=0.$  For example let $v\perp w$ and $Y=\langle \cdot ,v\rangle w.$ Then $X=pI+Y$ satisfies $(X-pI)^2=0.$  The operator $X-pI$ cannot be represented as $X=aE+bF,$ where $E$ and $F$ are projections so that $EF=FE=0.$ Indeed if $$X-pI=aE+bF$$ then
$$0=(X-pI)^2=a^2E+b^2F$$ Multiplying by $E$ leads to $a=0.$ Hence $b=0.$ Thus $X$ cannot be represented as a linear combination of two nontrivial commuting projections whose product is equal $0.$

Let $p\neq q.$ Then for $$Y={1\over p-q}X-{q\over p-q}I $$ there holds $Y^2=Y.$ Hence $Y$ is a projection and
$$X=qI+(p-q)Y=pY+q(I-Y)$$
Summarizing the claim in OP holds if $p\neq q,$ but the projections $Y$ and $I-Y$ do not need to be orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see why $Y$ and $I-Y$ need not by orthogonal. $Y(I-Y) = Y-Y^2 =Y-Y=0$, so they are orthogonal by construction, aren't they?

Comment: They are complementary to each other, but orthogonality means that they are selfadjoint. This assumption is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Operators of the form $X=pE_p + qE_q$ don't give you in general all the solutions. For example, if $p$ and $q$ are real, these operators $X$ are always self-adjoint. But you can pick any invertible operator $T$ and then $TXT^{-1}$ is also a solution to your polynomial equation which is not self-adjoint in general, so it cannot be decomposed as a sum of projections with real coefficients. A similar argument works for $p$ and $q$ complex numbers, with the difference that now $X^*\neq X$ but $X^*=CXC$ with $C\colon H\to H$ some involution (that in the case of $H=\ell^2\mathbb{Z}$ is just the conjugation of complex vectors). Anyway, if you look for more explicit counterexamples, I would use this ideas to look for a $2\times 2$ matrix $X_0$ that disprove your claim, and then check that the operator $X_0\oplus p\,\text{Id}_{\ell^2\mathbb{Z}}$ is indeed a counterexample in an infinite dimensional space.

Comment: I don’t get your point. I am not asking for a different representation, I am asking for operators not allowing for this representation using projectors. They have been constructed explicitly - which looks ok - so instead of looking for a counter example one should check where the construction itself fails. In addition, applying your $T$ to the projectors $E_{p,q}$ one finds $(TE_{p,q}T^{-1})^2 = TE_{p,q}T^{-1}$ so everything looks fine.

Comment: Remark: We never used that $p,q$ should be real or that projectors should be selfadjoint. All that has been used are the projectors $E^2 = E$ and $1-E$. In two dimensions one can use $X = x_0 \, \text{id} + \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i \, \sigma_i$ with complex $x_0, x_i$ and $\sigma_i$ as the hermitean su(2) generators i.e. the Pauli matrices to explicitly construct arbitrary 2*2 matrices $X$ and the coefficients $b,c$ (which are complex in general). I don’t see any counter example.

Comment: But you asked for orthogonal projections, and orthogonal projections are self-adjoint operators. Otherwise, E_p and E_q are idempotents, that can be projections but not orthogonal projections, right?

Comment: Yes. Maybe the reason for the confusion is that the conditions I mentioned in the very beginning are too restrictive. All that is required is the polynomial equation with $p \neq q$ and the two projectors that can be constructed explicitly.